# parsing special characters in xml

Tags: xml, xml-parsing

i have an response xml with contains the line as

```
<Description>DVD +/- RW Drive (read/write CD & DVD)</Description>
```

when try to read this xml response and load it to xml document  it is throwing error as
 An error occurred while parsing EntityName.

i have changed  the above line as

```
<Description>DVD +/- RW Drive (read/write CD and DVD)</Description>
```

still the error exists can any one guide me where i have gone wrong

Comment: Please post the exact XML document (at http://pastebin.com if it's more than 5 lines, can be simplified/anonymized as long as the error still occurs) and the (full, but simplified) code used to parse it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Apache Commons Lang class StringEscapeUtils escapeXML method handle  to non-ASCII characters in XML
[Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your XML generator must replace `&` with `&amp;`.

Answer (score 0):

You can process the XML as XPL. XPL has the same structure as XML - the only difference is that the parser allows special characters in text fields. You can use the XPL process on its own or as a pre-processor into valid XML (i.e. transforms your special characters for you and other things). There's even a recent article explaining the use of Java Concurrency to eliminate the performance cost of pre-processing (into SAX). [eXtensible Process Language](http://hll.nu)